# How can I tell if a shape is combined or not?

Tags: c#, coreldraw

Given a `Shape` object, how can I tell if that shape is a combination of shapes or not?

I could use `BreakApartEx()` and get a ShapeRange which I could count, but I would rather not break a part the shape if possible.

I am using Corel Draw X7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a duplicate shape, then use BreakApartEX, and shaperange.count?
Then delete it.
So, you still maintain the original shape.

Comment: It is a good idea and I will most likely do it this way if I cant find another solution.

Comment: Here is a stab at doing as you suggest: https://gist.github.com/mgnslndh/6b696b0197c31ddc921c

Comment: @Magnus An alternative would be to create a duplicate shape, break apart, count, then undo the break apart & duplicate shape.  Begin Command Group and End Command Group could be used to make this a touch more robust (group the duplicate, then break apart, then count, then end the group, then undo once).  That will avoid spurious entries in your undo history.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try CScript.GetCurveSubpathCount.
You should add Curve Shape checking first.

Good luck

Comment: Is it guaranteed that you get same amount of shapes as there are subpaths when you break apart a shape?

Comment: @MagnusLindhe is it a curve like object, or something more complex like a blend group, you are breaking apart?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, but as we knew, combined object must be curve shape,
so there should be a code to check whether selected object is a curveshape.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, but as we knew, combined object must be curve shape,
so there should be a code to check whether selected object is a curveshape.

May be just simple code like this :

Dim s as shape
Dim l as long

For each s in activeselectionrange
if s.type=cdrcurveshape then
l = CorelScript.GetCurveSubpathCount
'You can display the subpath count as msg or in text box.
MsgBox "The shape has " & l & " subpath(s)", vbOKOnly, "MLindhe:)"
end if
next s